# Project created using JHipster is available to everyone?

Tags: jhipster

Hello folks i am newbie i wanted to know suppose i am creating a web application using JHipster. Will my code available to everyone?.
I mean will the code be submitted to open source community?

Answer (score 1):

The generated code belongs to you, it's not shared.

Now, if you're afraid of your code leaking out because you're working  in a highly secured domain (e.g. Finance), it's another story.

The generator is open source so you can audit what it does.

But it would be simpler to configure your firewall so that it blocks outgoing traffic while still allowing incoming traffic. Generator should require only getting artifacts from public repositories (npm, maven) during generation phase.

It's like using a compiler, how do you know that it does not upload your source code somewhere? Either you audit the compiler code or you protect yourself with a firewall specifically configured each time you use it.

Finally, you should evaluate the risk of leaking generated code which has usually little value in comparison with the code that you manual add which is where business value is.

Comment: Marziou How would I come to know?? How to check whether it isn't available to everyone??

Comment: It's public only if you make it so, the generated code is yours. Your project will not publish itself magically.

Comment: @vicpermir from his profile, he's working in banking and probably under PCI-DSS requirements or equivalent, he can't just trust a tool, he has to prove to an auditor that it's the case. I've been through this as well ;)